# Rails: How to link html multiple-choice questions to a database value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, formbuilder

I'm trying to get a user's quiz answers saved to a database. This presumably should happen when they click the 'get my results' button, but prior to that - how do I 'link' a question to the appropriate value in the database?
Here is my example quiz form partial (which gets rendered in my page view):

```
<%= form_for([current_user]) do |f| %>
  <h3>1. I have the final say in decisions made within the group I'm leading.</h3> 
  <div class="btn-group-vertical clearfix form-group" data-toggle="buttons">
          <label class="btn btn-primary text-left">
            <input name="options" id="option1" type="radio" onclick="multiChoiceClick(1, 1)">A. Always. I'm the leader and should have the final say
          </label>
          <label class="btn btn-primary text-left">
            <input name="options" id="option2" type="radio">B. Sometimes, but I think the group should make decisions if possible
          </label>
          <label class="btn btn-primary text-left">
            <input name="options" id="option3" type="radio">C. I generally don't get involved. The group can make their own decisions without my help
          </label>
  </div>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit("Get my results!") %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Just as an example, how do I get this question linking to the database?

I'm using the Devise gem to get users logged in and out (that's all working fine). My User model has_many :quiz_answers and the QuizAnswer model belongs_to :user.

Can anyone tell me the immediate next step?

Comment: what do you mean by  'link' a question to the appropriate value in the database?

Comment: I mean have the question set up so that, when the user eventually clicks 'get my results', the database is updated with the user's answer. What needs to be included in the form builder (or elsewhere) to set up that association?

Answer (score 0):

I think the next step is to use `fields_for :quiz_answers` in the form builder. In your `User` model you will have to add `accepts_nested_attributes_for :quiz_answers`. And in your controller you need to permit the relevant parameters. Also see the guide for [Nested Forms](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can I ask you WHERE you found out about the accepts_nested_attributes method? (Is it a method?). And how would I find this information directly?

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods/accepts_nested_attributes_for

Comment: @moosefetcher I think that I first found out about it in this Railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

Comment: @moosefetcher It is also mentioned in the guide that I linked to (section 9.1).

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I have to say I'm not currently a fan of Rails' habit of doing things 'for' you. Removing the underscores from variable names and capitalising for Object names, for instance. 'Creating' a differently-named method from 'accepts_nested_attributes_for :symbol' for another. There are a lot of esoteric leaps to be aware of and it currently all seems very ambiguous.

Comment: I'm re-reading section 9 and I don't understand, in the code just below 9.2, what the :addresses symbol references. Does the accepts_nested_attributes_for line also create a :addresses accessor? If I wanted to display questions, would the User model then hold the questions? That doesn't seem to make much sense...

Comment: The example in the guide is the situation where a user has many addresses and should be able to update the addresses' information together with the user's information. First, the relationship in the model is defined as a one to many (`has_many :addresses`). Then, the `User` model also accepts attributes for that association `accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses`. In the form, the `f.fields_for :addresses` introduces a new scope so that you can build inputs for each associated address.

Comment: Thanks again. I'm asking how that would be applied to my situation. I'm guessing I shouldn't be adding :questions to a User. Should the initial form_for (at the top of the form) be passed a quiz object then? It seems like it would make more sense for a Quiz to have :questions...

Comment: And if I SHOULD be passing a Quiz, how would I do that? The line in the page that renders the quiz form is just: render "quizform" (with Rails tags) so I'm not sure how I'd pass a Quiz object - or where this would 'come from'.

Comment: Ok, are you trying to do this through Devise's controllers or have you created some controllers of your own?

Comment: I have created controllers of my own, but I have no idea if I have done that in the 'right' way. I don't have a very clear idea of where resources 'come from'. I'm used to instantiating things IN MY CODE, but it seems like Rails does that behind the scenes or something. I'd just like to know how to make a simple quiz. Surely this should be simple.

Comment: I see. The general idea in Rails is that the controllers are responsible for fetching objects that can be used in views, and modifying them in response to user actions. In your code example above, the `current_user` is a helper method from Devise that gives you the logged in user object. So, depending on how you want to build your application, the form could be for the current user (in a simple case), or a quiz object assigned in a controller if that is a more prominent feature of the app. If you need more advice, please update your question with some controller and model code (associations)